# Carrierwave difference between resizing options

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, carrierwave, image-resizing

I am trying to understand the difference between `resize_to_fill`, `resize_to_fit`, and `resize_to_limit`.

Say I have two images.  Image A is 500x300 and image B is 300x100

`resize_to_fill` 300 x 300
A - will just slice off 200 pixels of width?
B - will blow it up to 900x300 and then slice off 600px of width?

`resize_to_fit` 300 x 300
A - will shrink it down to 300x180?
B - will not change anything?

`resize_to_limit` -- not sure what the difference between this one and `resize_to_fit` is..

Can someone explain in a way that's easy to understand?

Comment: Why do you not try all the options and see what happens? Also there is an explanation here: http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/RMagick.html

Comment: @bonzo The explanations in that link are terrible.  I couldn't figure out how to use the methods in the console to experiment.